# Determine if a camera is observing a particular polygon

Tags: polygon, spatial-analyst

Does anyone have any ideas on how we could determine if a camera is observing a particular polygon?
I only have the below parameters from the camera.

- Camera Focal Length (Milimiteres)
- Camera Angle (in degrees ranging from 0 to 360): The direction of view.
- Camera Altitude (Meter): the distance between the camera and the ground.
- camera type (perspective, spherical, and fisheye)
- Camera image height and width dimensions: Pixel height and width.

Moreover, I have a location stored in POLYGON in wkt format (EPSG:4326) as follows: `((-73.99448741124245 40.75006303009828, -73.99455702291928 40.749965988800426, -73.9945885388752 40.749979704452535, -73.99451959775062 40.75007674573036, -73.99448741124245 40.75006303009828)`
My ultimate objective is to determine whether the camera's field of view intersects with this polygon. Do you suggest any methods or papers that can be used for this purpose?

Below is a sample of values, with the orange columns representing camera values and the yellow columns representing location data.
[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/139347/discussion-on-question-by-negin-zarbakhsh-determine-if-a-camera-is-observing-a-p).

Answer (score 0):

Use your latitudes, longitudes, and azimuths to plot the location and angle of one of your images in something like Google Earth.  For Example, this image of St Catherine of Siena Church (your image 511061303578324.png) is a good example.

[image]

Here is the church  [visible in Google Maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/The+Church+of+Saint+Catherine+of+Siena/@40.7651008,-73.9573796,48m/data=!3m1!1e3!4m6!3m5!1s0x89c258c248336ddd:0x670f720dc22be6ba!8m2!3d40.7650907!4d-73.9571567!16s%2Fm%2F0g55qxs?hl=en) .

Use the image coordinates and GIS imagery to estimate the image view width increase per meter distance to the church walls from your point location.  Once you have a good idea of the image width increase for each camera type use that value, the location coordinates and azimuth to manually draw lines estimating the camera view (see [pyshape](https://pypi.org/project/pyshp/) for creating easy geometries). Add an attribute to your shapefile with the image name.  Use the resulting geometries find the images that intersects your polygon of interest using GIS select by location tools.

Of course, this will all be limited to the accuracy and precision of the GNSS unit and the magnetometer of your equipment, and the spatial accuracy of the imagery you use to make these measurements.

Comment: Thanks, it is a very interesting approach and I am going to try it to see the results